# C++, How many addresses do arrays have?

Tags: c++, arrays

Does the array in c++ have address for each element? Or the array has just one address?

Answer (score 7):

Given an array like:

```
int a[4];
```

each of the 4 `int` in `a` has its own address (separated by the size of an `int` on your platform).

The address of `a` is simply the address of the first `int` in the array. So you can think of an array as having just one address, that is also the address of the first element. But all the elements of the array have their own address which can be used to refer to the elements. In fact, you can even access the individual bytes of each element, but you should be careful when interpreting what those bytes mean, depending on the data type of the elements.

Comment: Additionally, each byte of each element has its own address.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each element of an array has own address. Address of an array is the address of it's first element.

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    int n[10];
    if (std::begin(n) == &n[0]) {
        std::cout << "equal";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not equal";
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
equal
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an object *is* some bytes in memory. We call the location of the first of those bytes it's address. Nearly everything is an object (only functions and references aren't).

An array object *is* the elements (they are "subobjects" of the array).

So the array has an address, and each element has an address.

Answer (score 0):

Since almost everything in C++ can be "addressed" in some fashion, a C++ array has *at least* as many addresses as elements.

That is for an array like:

```
int x[16];
```

There is an equivalent `int*` address for each of `x[0]` through `x[15]`, as you can always do `&x[0]` through `&x[15]` and so on. In some cases you can even address individual bytes, like by recasting as `char*`.

In this case all of the addresses are *contiguous* so the only address that really matters is the first, or `x[0]`. Everything else can be computed based on that. Here `x[n]` is actually `*(&x[0] + n)` where it's doing pointer math internally, applying an offset of `n * sizeof(int)` to the base `&x[0]` pointer.

In the case of a two-dimensional array things get tricky as you can have contiguous arrays like:

```
int x[16][16];
```

And you can have non-contiguous arrays of pointers, like:

```
int* x[16];
```

Where in both cases you can do `x[y][z]` in code but the *meaning* is entirely different. In the second case there's a separate pointer for *each* top-level entry in the array, and these will differ such that `x[0]` and `x[1]` may not be anywhere close at all, and `x[2]` might be in the middle of them, memory-layout-wise, due to how the allocation was performed.

In that case you have at minimum 17 addresses necessary to retrieve all of the entries.

That being said, in C++ code you normally don't care how many "addresses" there are, you're more concerned with what a pointer represents and how large the allocation is so you don't access memory out-of-bounds.